# Xtext, import my own mydsl file

Tags: java, xtext, xtend

In my grammar i have an include rule as follow :

```
Script:
    includes+=(Include)* assignments+=(Assignment)* clock=Clock? tests+=Test*
;

Include:
    'INCLUDE' importURI=STRING
;
```

what I want to do is to include files same as the "main" file.

I'm working with an `interpreter` that handels the .mydsl file.

```
/* Main exec methode  */

def dispatch void exec(Script s) {

    s.includes.forEach[ i | i.exec]  
    s.assignments.forEach[a | a.exec]
    s.clock.exec
    s.tests.forEach[t|t.exec]
}

/* include methode */
def dispatch void exec(Include i) {

    System.out.println( i.importURI + " included")

}
```

Comment: looks more like a `Include: 'INCLUDE' includedScript=[Script|STRING];` + a name provider that calculated the name from the scripts resources uri.

Comment: I don't think that I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xtext imports are not includes. Xtext does not support includes at all. All that Xtext supports are Cross References. You can use namespace based or import uri based global scoping to determine how elements from other files can be found. assume you really want to follow the includes files in your interpreter

```
Script:
    includes+=(Include)*
;

Include:
    'INCLUDE' includedScript=[Script|STRING]
;
```

And Name Provider

```
public class MyDslQNP extends DefaultDeclarativeQualifiedNameProvider {

    QualifiedName qualifiedName(Script script) {
        return QualifiedName.create(script.eResource().getURI().trimFileExtension().lastSegment(), script.eResource().getURI().fileExtension());
    }

}
```

then you can follow the reference in your interpreter

```
class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {

    override bindIQualifiedNameProvider() {
        MyDslQNP
    }

}
```

Comment: excuse me, but how do I "follow" the reference in my interpreter. 
I created the MyDslQnp class in the package where I have the interpreter, is that right?

Comment: noooooo. you simply bind the nameprovider in runtime module.and create it somewhere around it. in your intepreter simply call myInclude.getIncludedScript()`

Comment: I will do something like this  class MyDslRuntimeModule extends AbstractMyDslRuntimeModule {
    override bindIValueConverterService() {
        return MyDslValueConverters
    }
  @Override
 public Class<? extends IQualifiedNameProvider> bindIQualifiedNameProvider() {
  return MyDslQNP.class
 }
}
but the runtime is in xtend and this code in java. I have errors that I can't correct, any ideas ?

Comment: i asssumed it would be no problem for you to switch between java and xtend and do the binding. i updated the answer

Comment: I still have a probleme. the script to be included has some declaration on it. but I'm note able to access them

Comment: well yes so you need includes and imports?!?
Then you need to implement this. since i dont know what you implemented regarding global scoping it is hard to tell. can you please elaborate?

Comment: not need to, I was missing something in my own code. it's working now.
 Answer accepted